# Does using WP-cron make the site slower for the user?

Tags: plugins, performance, wp-cron, cron, maintenance

Forgive my "beginnerness" in this matter but I have 2 options to trigger a heavy task (massive update on users' properties to solve an issue between 2 plugins that weren't meant to cooperate):

- (1) Use Unix Cron in my server OR
- (2) Use WP-Cron

I do prefer to do everything IN WordPress and use WP-Cron if they are similiar but (from my undestanding) since wp-cron is a pseudo-cron that waits for some visitor to come and trigger it, I fear it might be too heavy of a task to slow user's experience during navigation.

Does it have the potential to do so? **Should we actually use Unix Cron whenever possible to try to perform most of maintenance tasks** ideally when there's low traffic or no traffic at all?

Thank you very much for the help :D !

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-time maintenance issue then run the code manually at a time you chose.

If it's a periodic maintenance task that might be heavy, use unix cron.

Otherwise, wp-cron can be used.  You're probably using it more than you know already.  This [plugin is great for monitoring wp-cron](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/).

Comment: It's a monthly sync between plugins and yep, I was counting on Wp-crontrol if I choose to go for the Wp-cron version. The plugin's really helpful. Thank you for the answer ;) !

Comment: Please click the green marker next to my answer.  More info on how stackoverflow works: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I still can't upvote you because apparently I am too noob in this platform but I wanted to let you know that your information was useful :) I did click on the marker though :)